# What is the porpose of org.atmosphere.spring.SpringInjector

Tags: spring, atmosphere

As the name says this class should inject some beans from spring context to some place. But how it works? I can't find any examples with it.

Basically I need to inject some model services from spring context into Atmosphere-Jersey resource classes. Can this class help me?

Answer (score 0):

According to the source code of [SprigInjector](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/blob/atmosphere-1.0.x/extras/spring/src/main/java/org/atmosphere/spring/SpringInjector.java), you should be able to "inject" (@Autowired) any Atmosphere resource in your @Controllers or Services (or anything else under the spring scope). So I do not think you can inject/autowire your services inside your atmosphere resource with SpringInjector.